# Нанесение текста на изображение с переносом строки c помощью GD

Tags: gd, php

Всем привет. Создаю функцию на PHP по нанесению текста на изображение. Все удачно получилось с помощью библиотеки GD, но есть одно НО, которое не получается реализовать. Если текст больше изображение, он выходит за поля, мне же нужно, чтобы он оставался в центре и если нужно переходил на новую строку. Что можно дописать в функцию, чтобы делать перенос на новую строку, если ширина текста, больше ширины изображения. Возможно ли это? Если да, то как? Заранее спасибо.

**Сама функция:**

```
  // Константы положения водяного знака на картинке 
define ("WATERMARK_LEFT_BOTTOM",0); 
define ("WATERMARK_LEFT_TOP",1); 
define ("WATERMARK_RIGHT_BOTTOM",2); 
define ("WATERMARK_RIGHT_TOP",3); 
define ("WATERMARK_CENTER",4);
define ("WATERMARK_CENTER_BOTTOM",5);
define ("WATERMARK_CENTER_TOP",6);

function Watermark_Image($picture, $new_image, $font, $font_size, $marker, 
                         $watermark_position=WATERMARK_CENTER_BOTTOM) { 
  // Проверки на наличие файлов и допустимые параметры 
  if (!file_exists($picture)) { return false; } 
  if (!file_exists($font)) { return false; } 
  if ($font_size<10) { return false; } 
  if (($marker=trim($marker))=="") { return false; }

  // Получить размеры исходного изображения 
  list ($sx,$sy)=GetImageSize($picture); 
  if ($sx==0 || $sy==0) { return false; }

  $dst_im=imageCreatetruecolor($sx,$sy);

  // Определить цвета для нанесения водяных знаков 
  $black=ImageColorAllocate($dst_im,0,0,0); 
  $white=ImageColorAllocate($dst_im,255,255,255);

  // Если расширения нет, то выход с ошибкой 
  $pocket=Array(); 
  eregi("\.([a-z]*)$",$picture,$pocket); 
  if ($pocket[1]=="") { return false; }

  // На основании расширения создать картинку 
  switch (strtolower($pocket[1])) { 
    case "jpeg": 
    case "jpg": { 
      if (!$im=@ImageCreateFromJpeg($picture)) { return false; } 
      break; 
    } 
    case "gif": { 
      if (!$im=@ImageCreateFromGif($picture)) { return false; } 
      break; 
    } 
    case "png": { 
      if (!$im=@ImageCreateFromPng($picture)) { return false; } 
      break; 
    } 
    default: { return false; } 
  }

  ImageCopyResampled($dst_im, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $sx, $sy, $sx, $sy); 
  imageDestroy($im);

  // Получить координаты блока под текст 
  list($lnx,$lny,$rnx,$rny,$rvx,$rvy,$lvx,$lvy) = 
     ImageTTFBBox($font_size,0,$font,$marker);

  // Вычислить размеры блока 
  $text_width=$rnx-$lnx; 
  $text_height=$rny-$rvy;

  // Получить координаты блока на картинке для нанесения надписи 
  switch ($watermark_position) { 
    case WATERMARK_LEFT_BOTTOM: { 
      $pos_x=10; 
      $pos_y=$sy-10; 
      break; 
    } 
    case WATERMARK_RIGHT_BOTTOM: { 
      $pos_x=$sx-$text_width-10; 
      $pos_y=$sy-10; 
      break; 
    } 
    case WATERMARK_LEFT_TOP: { 
      $pos_x=10; 
      $pos_y=$text_height+10; 
      break; 
    } 
    case WATERMARK_RIGHT_TOP: { 
      $pos_x=$sx-$text_width-10; 
      $pos_y=$text_height+10; 
      break; 
    } 
    case WATERMARK_CENTER: { 
      $pos_x=intval($sx/2-$text_width/2); 
      $pos_y=intval($sy/2+$text_height/2); 
      break; 
    } 
    case WATERMARK_CENTER_BOTTOM: { 
      $pos_x=intval($sx/2-$text_width/2); 
      $pos_y=$sy-20;
      break; 
    }
    case WATERMARK_CENTER_TOP: { 
      $pos_x=intval($sx/2-$text_width/2); 
      $pos_y=$text_height+20;
      break; 
    } 
    default: { return false; } 
  }

  // Подсчитать количество светлых и темных пикселов в блоке 
  $dark=0; 
  $light=0;

  for ($x=0; $x<$text_width; $x++) { 
    for ($y=0; $y<$text_height; $y++) { 
      $color=imageColorAt($dst_im,($pos_x+$x),($pos_y+$y-$text_height)); 
      list($r,$g,$b)=array_values(imageColorsForIndex($dst_im,$color)); 
      if (($r+$g+$b)<(128*3)) { $dark++; } else { $light++; } 
    } 
  }

  // В зависимости от количества светлых и темных точек нанести 
  // светлую или темную надпись 
  if ($light>$dark) { 
    // Темный текст со светлой рамкой 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x-1,$pos_y-1,$white,$font,$marker); 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x,$pos_y-1,$white,$font,$marker); 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x+1,$pos_y-1,$white,$font,$marker);

    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x-1,$pos_y,$white,$font,$marker); 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x+1,$pos_y,$white,$font,$marker);

    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x-1,$pos_y+1,$white,$font,$marker); 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x,$pos_y+1,$white,$font,$marker); 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x+1,$pos_y+1,$white,$font,$marker);

    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x,$pos_y,$black,$font,$marker); 
  } 
  else { 
    // Светлый текст с темной рамкой 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x-1,$pos_y-1,$black,$font,$marker); 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x,$pos_y-1,$black,$font,$marker); 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x+1,$pos_y-1,$black,$font,$marker);

    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x-1,$pos_y,$black,$font,$marker); 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x+1,$pos_y,$black,$font,$marker);

    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x-1,$pos_y+1,$black,$font,$marker); 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x,$pos_y+1,$black,$font,$marker); 
    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x+1,$pos_y+1,$black,$font,$marker);

    ImageTTFText($dst_im,$font_size,0,$pos_x,$pos_y,$white,$font,$marker); 
  }

  // Записать измененный файл на место 
  switch (strtolower($pocket[1])) { 
    case "jpeg": 
    case "jpg": { 
      ImageJPEG($dst_im,$new_image,90); 
      break; 
    } 
    case "gif": { 
      ImageGIF($dst_im,$new_image); 
      break; 
    } 
    case "png": { 
      ImagePNG($dst_im,$new_image); 
      break; 
    } 
  } 
  imageDestroy($dst_im); 
  return true; 
}
```

После долгого поиска в интернете, понял, что текст переносится с помощью "n" и под нее дописал функцию:

*Вставляется в самом начале после определения ширины картинки:*

```
$ret = "";

$arr = explode(' ', $marker);
$wrp = 0;

foreach ( $arr as $word ){

    $teststring = $ret.' '.$word;
    $testbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $teststring);
    if ( $testbox[2] > $sx ){
        $ret.=($ret==""?"":"\n").$word;
        $wrp=$wrp+1;
    } else {
        $ret.=($ret==""?"":" ").$word;
    }

}

$marker = $ret;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на сколько мне известно автопереноса нет в библиотеке. Код ваш не читал. Но я бы пступил следубщим образом:

1. Вариант 1- если водяной знак не вмещается - то в цикле уменьшаем шрифт и проверяем входит или нет.
2. Вариант 2 - если нельзя уменьшать - то в цикле делаем перенос сами - тоесть работаем со строкой - делим ее на части и выводим уже текст частями

Comment: Спасибо, решил. Ответ написал в конце вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен перенос строк, то wordwrap()